createNewFile not work - file not created ( Kotlin. Android Studio )
I use createNewFile() but file not create. I use "Pixel 8 API 34" emulator.
Code being carried out in try{} until isNewFileCreated, and then moves to catch(error: Exception){}
isNewFileCreated is "false" but file not exist
*`//------------Kotlin:

private var filename: String = "readme.txt"
private lateinit var newFile: File

fun cfile() {

    val isNewFileCreated: Boolean

    try {
        newFile = File("/data/data/com.example.myapplication2/files/",filename)
        isNewFileCreated = newFile.createNewFile()
    }
    catch (error: FileNotFoundException) {
          error.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (error: Exception) {
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}`*
//-------------------

I try to add .use {} in try {}, but when "fun cfile()" is run a second time - isExist == true, but isNewFileCreated == false
`//-----kotlin

 try {

     newFile = File("/data/data/com.example.myapplication2/files/",filename)

     isExist = setFile.exists()

     val sFile = FileOutputStream(setFile)

     sFile.use {
        isNewFileCreated = setFile.createNewFile()
     }
 } 
 catch { ...`

 I assume that this problem is only in the latest versions of SDK.


dont hardcode that file path, it might not be the same across devices. instead you should be using File(context.filesDir, filename)

Add full details of the exception. Do you checked whether the directory exists?

Since createNewFile throws an exception, isNewFileCreated does not get set, and it's pointless checking its value when an exception has been caught. You need to check the full details of the exception.

For your second piece of code, you say "isExist == true, but isNewFileCreated == false". Have you read the documentation? It says that createNewFile() returns false if the file already exists. So why are you surprised?

whatever I do "/data/data/com.example.myapplication2/files/readme.txt" not created

It doesn't get created because it already exists.
